# Why is not possible to defragment ubuntu's disk?

Tags: data-structures

Someone can explain me why we can't  defragment ubuntu's disk? Or generally linux machines

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic here, as it's about a specific operating system. It might be on-topic on another site on the network.

Comment: This is a question for [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/), or perhaps [Unix&Linux.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  It's also (as [@Ricardo Cruz](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/47449/ricardo-cruz)'s answer point's out), based of a fallacy.

Answer (score 4):

*"why we can't defragment ubuntu's disk?"*

Who said you couldn't?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/221079/how-to-defrag-an-ext4-filesystem